# Не запускается ajenti на Дебиан 8

Tags: python, debian

Установил на чистый сервер  с Debian 8 панель управления Ajenti, сервис запускается в консоле показывает Active. Но когда переходишь по ссылке https://ip.servera:8000, не заходит на панель.

Debug list:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gevent/greenlet.py", line 327, in run
result = self._run(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gevent/server.py", line 102, in wrap_socket_and_handle
ssl_socket = self.wrap_socket(client_socket, **self.ssl_args)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gevent/ssl.py", line 382, in wrap_socket
ciphers=ciphers)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gevent/ssl.py", line 84, in __init__
ctx = SSLContext(ssl_version)
NameError: global name 'SSLContext' is not defined
<Greenlet at 0x7f1b84782eb0: <bound method
SocketIOServer.wrap_socket_and_handle of <SocketIOServer at 0x7f1b83c57190 fileno=6 address=0.0.0.0:8000>>(<socket at 0x7f1b83de2390 fileno=12 sock=192.168.0, ('91.231.255.246', 58413)) > failed with NameError
```

Comment: Устанавливали по [инструкции](http://support.ajenti.org/topic/349864-installing-on-debian/)? Возможно, `SSLContext` отсутствует в [вашей версии](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28228233) python.

Comment: Да, устанавливал по инструкции. Может быть, как установить нужную версию python? У меня в директории /usr/local/lib/  два питона, питон 2.7 и 3.4

Comment: Посмотрите версию `python -V`. Я так понимаю, `SSLContext` появилось только с версии *2.7.9*.

Comment: Оказывается проблема была в gevent. Если у кого возникнет данная ошибка сделайте откат gevent на версию 1.1b3 или 1.1b4 командой `sudo easy_install -U gevent==1.1b4`

Comment: @approximatenumber нет, **не надо так делать**. Ответы должны быть ответами.

Comment: @pwnz22 если у вас есть решение - опубликуйте его как **ответ** ))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение от автора:

Чтобы решить данную проблему, откатите gevent до версии `1.1b3` или `1.1b4` с помощью `easy_install -U gevent==1.1b4`